# What language/ software does Rosetta stone use?

Tags: audio

Rosetta stone allows you to speak and check you pronunciation with the native speaker, what programming language would such a feature be built in or what server/clientside software would be necessary?

Comment: Programming language with this feature built in?  None.

Comment: Sure, not built in, but what language would I have to build it in? For example PHP doesn't come with a blog built into it, but if I want to create a blog I can use php. What programming language would I need to use to create a web program that a user can input audio and I can check two audio files to see if they are similar in sound and pronunciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I'll take a crack at this question, even though it's pretty vague and I've never used Rosetta Stone.

First, if your program was running within a web browser (I assume that's your goal since you said *create a web program*,) you'll need to be able to capture audio locally.  Obviously, you wouldn't want to require the user to upload audio files they've created.  This would typically be done with Adobe Flash, but I'm sure you could also use Silverlight, Java, or an unmanaged browser extension specific to each browser you want to support.

Getting the audio is probably the easy part.  Processing the actual wave form for pronunciation would be fairly tricky.  You'd have to match each phoneme, making sure it was valid, and making sure the right parts of the word were accentuated.  I doubt it would make much sense to have this sort of linguistic data down on the client, and I doubt something like Flash would be very good at doing this sort of wave form analysis anyway.  Most likely, these samples are uploaded to a server where they are analyzed for correctness.  This could be done in pretty much any programming language, so one could only guess how Rosetta did it.  Perhaps Java code, pure C++, or .NET.